How to send hidden data in a URL in NextJs13
I'm trying to send some hidden data in a URL redirect in NextJs 13.
I'm using the next router like this
is my actual URL
let url = `/blog/view/${BlogType}/${blogId}`

I want to hide the parameter data from the URL so I'm using router.push(url, as, options):
router.push({pathname: url,query: data,},url,);
it redirects me to a new component as expected and I get the data in URL query but on page refresh, there is no data in URL query.
I'm also using Redux state library but the same thing happens with the state when I refresh the page it loses the data
what are possible ways to get the hidden data on URL redirect and keep the same data on page reload or refresh

What kind of hidden data are you passing?

im trying to pass json data for use in next component

If you want the data to be present even after page refresh you would need to store it in either sessionStorage or localStorage API's

the user can have duplicate tabs for same or different blogs which will effect the local or session storage and this way i would have to manage different identities for each json object, so i want to avoid that and want to use the url props so that the loaded page will have its own data object only

Just before doing router.push({pathname: url,query: data,},url,);, you could do something like
const hiddenData = {}; // Some Data
localStorage.setItem('hidden-component-data', JSON.stringify(hiddenData));
router.push({pathname: url,query: data,},url,);

And in the routed component
const hiddenDataString = localStorage.getItem('hidden-component-data');
const hiddenData = JSON.parse(hiddenDataString)

If you want the data to be present only until the browser tab is open you could change localStorage to sessionStorage.
Without storage API, encoding the hidden data and passing it in URL might work
const hiddenData = {a: '123'};
const encodedHiddenData = btoa(JSON.stringify(data));
router.push({
   pathname: url, 
   query: {...data, otherData: encodedHiddenData},
   url
})

And in the routed component
const searchParams = useSearchParams()
const hiddenDataParam = searchParams.get('otherData') ?? btoa('{}');
const hiddenData = JSON.parse(atob(hiddenDataParam));


can we do it without local and session storage. like url props
